# MoveIt: get current desired end effector pose

Tags: ros, moveit, tracking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am trying to get access to the current desired end effector's transform output by MoveIt (actually my goal is to compute the tracking error). My feeling is that I need to do the following steps:

- Get the desired joint angles from MoveIt
- Parse the urdf (to build a direct geometric model), or is there a package which computes the direct geometric model of the robot out of its urdf?
- Compute the end effector's desired transform from the geometric model and the desired joint angles

Am I right?

Now a question more related to code:

I guess the desired joint angles are provided by moveit in topic **/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal**, no? This topic is of type `control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal` ([api in ROS Kinetic](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html)). I also guess the trajectory is in field **goal.trajectory.points.positions**. fields **points** and **positions** are arrays: do you know how I should interpret them? Also does the fact that these are arrays mean that the whole desired trajectory is sent at one and not per small time steps?

Thansk!

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189345/moveit:-get-current-desired-end-effector-pose/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could be just English wording, but I guess by "desired" you mean "commanded", or the order MoveIt! sends to ROS network. If I'm right, then you basically get things right I think.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-25**:
If 'commanded', then yes (although this would be at the level `MoveIt<->controller`, not `controller<->hw`). If 'current', then no.